# AND operator not working in a PHP function using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a function with MySQL to change password but the `AND` operator is not working properly.

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%'
FUNCTION temp_staff.fn_changePassword(user_id INT, oldPassword VARCHAR(255), newPassword VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
update temp_staff.tbl_user set password = newPassword WHERE user_id = user_id AND password = oldPassword;
RETURN 1;
END
```

Result: it fetches 3 rows but in my table user_id is primary key, so give me proper solution.

Comment: Is not not easier to change the user pass by an 'Update' function? Or i'm missing something

Comment: @Perrykipkerrie  It's just field updating, not changing password for mysql user.

Comment: how do you know it is fetching 3 rows? it is not fetching anything.  Does this query return any data? `select user_id from temp_staff.tbl_user group by user_id having count(user_id)>1`

Comment: Sorry then it is out of my reach, sorry for the inconvience

Comment: I need a proper query to update password with old password, i pass user_id and old password to fetch my records from the tbl_user table but My AND operator not work properly

Comment: Hello Friends, Thanks for your help but i found solution for it own my self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE user_id = user_id` will always evaluate to true (unless null).  You should either rename the function parameter so that it doesn't conflict with the column name, or else table-qualify the reference to the table column.